# read file from file pointer without using readlines

Tags: python

can someone help me fix this code I keep getting this error, I'm struggling.

for every code I practice, I keep getting the same error

This is the **customers.txt** file for this question that we are supposed to work with

```
12345,Tom,Black,300.00,1998-01-30
23456,Alice,Smith,1200.50,1998-02-20
14567,Jane,White,900.00,1998-07-01
43564,Weilin,Zhao,450.25,1998-01-03
45432,Bina,Mehta,278.95,1998-03-21
```

```
def customer_first(fh):
    record = None
    lines = fh.readlines()
    i = 0
    while i < len(lines):
        line = lines[i]
        values = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
        if record == None or values[4] < record[4]:
            record = values
        i += 1
    return record
```

...

**Sample testing:**

Find customer with earliest sign-in:

['43564', 'Weilin', 'Zhao', '450.25', '1998-01-03']

this is the error I keep getting down below.

**Test for calls to forbidden Python functions: 'readlines'**

ERROR:

function should not call 'readlines'

these are all the things I'm being tested on in my code:

Test various parameters: 'customers file variable'

OK

Test for calls to forbidden Python functions: 'input'

OK

Test for calls to forbidden Python functions: 'print'

OK

Test for calls to forbidden Python functions: 'readlines'

ERROR:

function should not call 'readlines'

Test for calls to forbidden Python functions: 'open'

OK

Test for calls to forbidden Python functions: 'close'

OK

Test function docstring documentation:

OK

Test for multiple returns:

OK

Test that the function does not use 'for':

OK

Test that the function does not hard code the length of the file:

OK

Test for misuse of function name:

OK

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show how you're calling this function. Also, please choose a title that clearly describes your problem. This is too generic to be searchable. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use `readlines()` to loop over a file - just do `for line in fh`.

Comment: the instructions say that we need to use while loop and not for loop

Comment: The error you're getting isn't from Python itself, it's from whatever framework is used to grade your answers. It's telling you not to use `readlines`.

Comment: Use `read` instead of `readlines` to read the whole file into a single string, and then use `splitlines` on that string to create a list of lines that the code you have will iterate over...or can you not use `splitlines` either?  It's impossible to be sure what you want when you haven't told us what constraints have been placed on you as to what you can and can't use.

Comment: I'm kinda still confused as to what you exactly mean, do you mind illustrating what you are saying to my code I  will highly appreciate it.

Comment: i will add what is acceptable to have in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your grading system might expect this, as an alternative to using `.readlines`():

```
def customer_first(fh):
    record = None
    lines = fh.read().split('\n')
    i = 0
    while i < len(lines):
        line = lines[i]
        values = line.split(',')
        if record == None or values[4] < record[4]:
            record = values
        i += 1
    return record
```

Here, we call `.read()` to read the *whole* file in at once, and then `.split()` it into individual lines for each line break. This is essentially what `.readlines()` probably does under the hood, and is the most direct replacement for your code that doesn't use that method.

---

Your grading system might also be expecting you to do this:

```
def customer_first(fh):
    record = None
    i = 0
    line = fh.readline()
    while line != '':
        values = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
        if record == None or values[4] < record[4]:
            record = values
        line = fh.readline()
    return record
```

`File.readline()` is similar to `File.readlines()` except that it returns only one line, and returns an empty string if you've reached the end of the file.

---

Another alternate solution is to iterate through the file with `next()`, and use a `try`/`except` block to catch a `StopIteration` (which is how `for` loops actually work under the hood). This is a more complicated, more advanced, and more niche method, though, which I think it's unlikely your teacher expects you to be using here unless this is something you've just learned about:

```
def customer_first(fh):
    record = None
    i = 0
    try:
        line = next(fh)
        while line != '':
            values = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
            if record == None or values[4] < record[4]:
                record = values
            line = next(fh)
    except StopIteration
        return record
```

---

I'd like to impress upon you that **using `for` loops when possible is generally good practice, using `.readlines()` in general is usually not bad practice when simply iterating over the file in a `for` loop isn't sufficient, and you shouldn't take this assignment as a sign to avoid doing these things in the future.** If the assignment doesn't tell you what tool you're supposed to be using, and the recent lectures you've had in class haven't covered one of the above intending to clue you into it, then it's my opinion this is a bad assignment.

Also, your code probably has a logic error (try `record == None and values[4] < record[4]`), but that's not the issue you're asking about, and once the grading system starts actually running your code, you'll get different error messages that would probably lead you to figuring it out anyway.

Comment: It's working now, Thank you so much I really appreciate it coz I have been stuck on the same problem for the past 3 hours. Now I understand my mistake. Thanks again for the classification.

Answer (score -2):

If you really *can't use readlines()* or the csv module then certainly you can loop over the file such as:

```
data=[line.split(',') for line in fh.read().splitlines()]
>>> data
[['12345', 'Tom', 'Black', '300.00', '1998-01-30'], ['23456', 'Alice', 'Smith', '1200.50', '1998-02-20'], ['14567', 'Jane', 'White', '900.00', '1998-07-01'], ['43564', 'Weilin', 'Zhao', '450.25', '1998-01-03'], ['45432', 'Bina', 'Mehta', '278.95', '1998-03-21']]
```

Since those are [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) style dates, no conversion from text needed. You can get the `min` this way:

```
>>> min(data, key=lambda sl: sl[4])
['43564', 'Weilin', 'Zhao', '450.25', '1998-01-03']
```

Comment: Dude.  If the OP isn't allowed to use `readlines`, there's no way that using a high-level module like `csv` is going to fly.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. We're not allowed to use CSV

Comment: Try the second part.